# Pandas groubpy and then join multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas

Given the following dataframe:

```
A   B   C
1   2   3
1   9   8

df = df.groupby(['A'])['B'].apply(','.join).reset_index()
```

this produces

```
A   B
1   2,9
```

However I also want to join the 'C' column values together with a comma the same way as b.

Expected:

```
A   B   C
1   2,9 3,8
```

I tried:

```
df = df.groupby(['A'])['B','C'].apply(','.join).reset_index()
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html):

```
df = df.groupby(['A'])['B','C'].agg(','.join).reset_index()
```